# Ubuntu theme went off after the reboot/turn off, how do I put it back?

Tags: 14.04, themes

I'm trying top use the Moka theme in Ubuntu 14.04 x64, but even with Unity twaek tool, nothing changes. The theme is always on Ambiance, and so the icons in the launchbar and the mouse arrow. Unfortunately, icons are applied in Control Panel only. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you applying some pack of Moka? Moka for the icons and for the the background theme is different things. Apply it with Ubuntu-Tweak it works.

Comment: I'm selecting Moka from the icon panel in UTT, and it doesn't work... I tried restarting, and it doeasn't work anyway. :(

Comment: how did you download your Moka set of themes and icons from where?

Comment: From the official site. There were commands ad I used them.

Comment: Here.
http://mokaproject.com/moka-icon-theme/#download-button

Comment: did you try to apply any other theme? does it work?

Comment: Nope. The theme doesn't want to change. :(

Comment: Exactly. Seems impossible.

Comment: what does it tell you in terminal? `apt-cache policy gtk2-engines-murrine`

Comment: gtk2-engines-murrine:
  Installato: 0.98.2-0ubuntu2
  Candidato:  0.98.2-0ubuntu2
  Tabella versione:
 *** 0.98.2-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: seems ok, maybe it's an issue with x64

Comment: But it's weird... i installed it, and everything went fine. The, i turned off the system and later... everything was gone. :(

Comment: did you try to simply reboot and try it again?

Comment: Alerady did, but one time more will not kill me...

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: I guess there must be some incompatibility issue with latest x64 update, I read on other forums users couldn't update Moka pacckage after recent updates on 14.04

Comment: Man... what a pity. :(

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) install `Ubuntu-Tweak`:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Open `Ubuntu-Tweak` from `Dash` then navigate to `tweaks` > `theme` and choose an appropriate themes:

[image]

P.S.

If your theme occasionally went off after reboot or anything and you cannot apply it anyhow, follow this workaround:

1. Launch `Ubuntu-Tweak` tool and at the theme section put/click everything to `default`.
2. Reboot the system.
3. Launch `Ubuntu-Tweak` again and apply theme now. It should work now.

Comment: Nothing changed. :(

Comment: follow my re-edited answer it should work.